# array to object codeigniter [REST API]

Tags: arrays, api, codeigniter, object

so i have an ouput data look like this [image]

and this is my code

```
$var1[] = array('0' => $about_us,
                '1' => $privacy,
                '2' => $term_condition,
                '3' => $copyright,
                '4' => $faq);
                    $var2[] = array('0' => $voucher_redemption,
                                 '1' => $contact_us);
                    $var3[] = array('0' => $about_point,
                                 '1' => $earn_point,
                                 '2' => $redeem_voucher);

                    $array["ABOUT"]=$var1;
                    $array["SUPPORT"]=$var2;
                    $array["POINT"]=$var3;
                    $final[]=$array;

                    $data["STATUS"] = "SUCCESS";
                    $data["MASSAGE"] = "LIST FOOTER TITLE";
                    $data["DATA"] = $final;
                   echo json_encode($data);
```

the problem is i want to return about [{"0":"about us"}] not only array

Comment: use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` constraints as second parameter to json_encode

Comment: Please clearly show your expected response of the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `$var2` as an object, not an array

```
$var2= new stdClass();


$var2->0 = $voucher......
```

Answer (score 0):

we can force that `json_encode` uses an object

```
json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
```

Comment: using your approach full array convert into JSON but the loop will not run with the response.

Comment: your decoded json is on object format so you can access it like object or add extra prameter while decoding json  
ex. json_decode($data,true);
it return array

Comment: I know that but I am telling this thing for mobile application and javascript.

Comment: can you share expected response so I can check accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();

foreach($todo->result() as $hasil) {

    $result[] = array(   
        'id_todo'         => $hasil->id_todo,                     
        'tanggal_input'   => $hasil->tanggal_input,
        'mapel'           => $hasil->mapel,
        'catatan'         => $hasil->catatan                        
    );
}
```